# What's the best way to load two pretrained model partially from state-dict in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pre-trained-model

I am trying to load two separately trained models except for the last layer and want to train the last layer separately combining these two models. I defined e new `nn.Module` class and load these pretrained model inside that class and in the forward path tried to return the value before the last layer.

```
class New_net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New_net, self).__init__()
        self.net1 = net1()
        self.net2 = net2()
        self.fc= nn.Linear(512, 2)
        self._initialize_weights()

    def _initialize_weights(self):
        checkpoint = torch.load('save_model/checkpoint_net1.t7')
        self.net1.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])

        checkpoint = torch.load('save_model/checkpoint_net2.t7')
        self.net2.load_state_dict(checkpoint['state_dict'])       

    def forward(self, x):
        x1 = self.net1(x)
        x2 = self.net2(x)
        x=torch.cat((x1,x2),dim=1)
        x=self.fc(x)
        return x
```

but it seems it is not loading the model accurately. What's the correct way to do that

Comment: Load the weights normaly for all layers afterwards execute 

``for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False`` 

and use model.fc =nn.Linear(512,2) to replace the last layer again with non frozen parameters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured that. Instead of weight initialization, I did the following

```
#load net1 model partially
checkpoint = torch.load('save_model/checkpoint_net1.t7')
pretrained_dict=checkpoint['state_dict']

net1_dict=net.net1.state_dict()
pretrained_dict = {k: v for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k in net1_dict}
net1_dict.update(pretrained_dict)
net.net1.load_state_dict(net1_dict)

#load net2 model partially
checkpoint = torch.load('save_model/checkpoint_net2.t7')
pretrained_dict=checkpoint['state_dict']
net2_dict=net.net2.state_dict()
pretrained_dict = {k: v for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k in net2_dict}
net2_dict.update(pretrained_dict)
net.net2.load_state_dict(net2_dict)
```